# Improve a clojure function

Tags: clojure

I have a homogeneous list of maps, like the following

```
({:x 1 :y 2} {:x 3 :y 5} {:x 1 :y 7} {:x 2 :y 0} {:x 3 :y -1})
```

I'd like to sum the `:y` values of the pairs with equal `:x` values.  I mean, I want a function `y-adder` that if applied to the preceding list gives the list (the order doesn't matter, it could be a set instead of a list)

```
({:x 1 :y 9} {:x 3 :y 4} {:x 2 :y 0})
```

What I wrote is the following:

```
(defn y-adder [Ps]
  (let [xs (set (map :x Ps))]
   (let [y+ (fn [v] (apply + (map :y (filter #(= (:x %) v) Ps))))]
    (map #(hash-map :x % :y (y+ %)) xs))))
```

It works, but it seems over-complicated for such a simple task.  So I'm wondering if there is a simpler (and maybe more efficient) solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me this is a bit simpler, but I haven't checked to see if it's more efficient.

```
> (for [[k v] (group-by :x xs)] {:x k :y (apply + (map :y v))})
({:x 1, :y 9} {:x 3, :y 4} {:x 2, :y 0})
```

The key is the `group-by`:

```
> (group-by :x xs)
{1 [{:x 1, :y 2} {:x 1, :y 7}],
 3 [{:x 3, :y 5} {:x 3, :y -1}],
 2 [{:x 2, :y 0}]}
```

Once you have that it's a short trip to your desired result.

Comment: Instead of map and then apply, consider `(transduce (map :y) + 0 v)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group-by`:

```
(defn y-adder [ps]
  (map (fn [[x-val matches]]
         {:x x-val :y (apply + (map :y matches))})
       (group-by :x ps)))
```